# Mysql change id in field is another field = "transfer"

Tags: mysql, sql, scripting

Im new to mysql and would like to know how i would say in code. if Narrive = "transfer" then change AccountID to 2001

please could some one give me a step by step on his and please explain where i would put this code as well because i have no clue.

Comment: Narrive and AccountID are cols within the database

Comment: i been told the code is                                                                                        update your_table
set accountid = 2001
where narrative = 'transfer'                                             but i do not know where to put this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE tableName
SET AccountID='2001'
WHERE Narrive="transfer"
```

Comment: UPDATE dbo.NLNominalTranType SET AccountNumber="2001" WHERE Narrative="transfer" my code and still not working. Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'Narrative'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'transfer'.

Comment: AccountNumber and Narrative are the column names. transfer is the string inside the field inside the narrative column

Comment: UPDATE tableName SET AccountNumber='2001' WHERE Narrive='transfer'

Comment: UPDATE dbo.NLNominalTranType SET AccountNumber='2001' WHERE Narrative='transfer' still got col invalid

Comment: Make sure that they are spelt correctly and match your column names identically.

Comment: Please select post as your final answer by clicking in the 0 next to my post.